# Unable to Save Keras checkpoints on CloudML (1.8) error: ImportError: `save_model` requires h5py

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After each epoch, I have the following callbacks:

1. Create a TensorBoard.
2. Save the model checkpoint.

However, after the 1st epoch of training I get the following traceback. I am assuming this is to do with the checkpoint callback.

Is this normal behaiviour?

My **callbacks.py** where all callbacks are created in `create_callbacks()`

```
def create_callbacks(job_dir, logs_path):

    checkpoint_path = 'checkpoint.{epoch:04d}-{val_loss:.9f}.hdf5'

    if not job_dir.startswith("gs://"):  # then local
        checkpoint_path = os.path.join(job_dir + 'checkpoints', checkpoint_path)

    checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True,
                                 save_weights_only=False,
                                 mode='auto', period=1)

    tb = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logs_path, batch_size=None, histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False)

    # Continuous eval callback
    export = ContinuousExport(eval_frequency=1, job_dir=job_dir)

    return [checkpoint, tb, export]


class ContinuousExport(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    """Continuous eval callback to evaluate the checkpoint once every so many epochs."""

    def __init__(self, eval_frequency, job_dir,):
        self.eval_frequency = eval_frequency
        self.job_dir = job_dir

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        print('Epoch number is {}'.format(epoch))
        print('Frequency is {}'.format(self.eval_frequency))
        if epoch > 0 and epoch % self.eval_frequency == 0:
            # Unhappy hack to work around h5py not being able to write to GCS.
            # Force snapshots and saves to local filesystem, then copy them over to GCS.
            model_path_glob = 'checkpoint.*'
            if not self.job_dir.startswith("gs://"):
                model_path_glob = os.path.join(self.job_dir + 'checkpoints', model_path_glob)
            checkpoints = sorted(glob.glob(model_path_glob), key=os.path.getmtime)
            print('Path is {}'.format(model_path_glob))
            print('Length of cp is {}'.format(len(checkpoints)))
            if len(checkpoints) > 0:
                print(checkpoints[-1])
                if self.job_dir.startswith("gs://"):
                    print('Copying the model to {}'.format(self.job_dir + '/checkpoints/'))
                    copy_file_to_gcs(self.job_dir + '/checkpoints/', checkpoints[-1])
                else:
                    print('Using local storage, not saving to GCS')
        else:
            print('\nEvaluation epoch[{}] (no checkpoints found)'.format(epoch))


def copy_file_to_gcs(job_dir, file_path):
    with file_io.FileIO(file_path, mode='rb') as input_f:
        with file_io.FileIO(os.path.join(job_dir, file_path), mode='w+') as output_f:
            output_f.write(input_f.read())
```

> INFO    2018-10-08 12:17:30 +0100       master-replica-0
>   Module completed; cleaning up. INFO    2018-10-08 12:17:30 +0100
>   master-replica-0                Clean up finished. ERROR   2018-10-08
>   12:18:23 +0100       service         The replica master 0 exited with
>   a non-zero status of 1.  ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100
>   service         Traceback (most recent call last): ERROR   2018-10-08
>   12:18:23 +0100       service           File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main ERROR 
>   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service             "**main**",
>   mod_spec) ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code ERROR
>   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service             exec(code,
>   run_globals) ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service
>   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line
>   167, in  ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service
>   train_model(train_file=train_file, test_file=test_file,
>   job_dir=job_dir, **arguments) ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100
>   service           File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line 59,
>   in train_model ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service
>   model = fit_model(model, train_g, test_g, callbacks) ERROR
>   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service           File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line 124,
>   in fit_model ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service
>   model.fit_generator(**params) ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100
>   service           File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 1598, in fit_generator ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100
>   service             initial_epoch=initial_epoch) ERROR   2018-10-08
>   12:18:23 +0100       service           File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training_generator.py",
>   line 231, in fit_generator ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100
>   service             callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs) ERROR
>   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service           File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/callbacks.py",
>   line 95, in on_epoch_end ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100
>   service             callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs) ERROR
>   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service           File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/callbacks.py",
>   line 468, in on_epoch_end ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100
>   service             self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True) ERROR
>   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service           File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/network.py",
>   line 1126, in save ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service
>   save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer) ERROR
>   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service           File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/saving.py",
>   line 75, in save_model ERROR   2018-10-08 12:18:23 +0100       service
>   raise ImportError('`save_model` requires h5py.') ERROR   2018-10-08
>   12:18:23 +0100       service         ImportError: `save_model`
>   requires h5py.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need install the package h5py.

h5py file is a container to store the trained model. If you don't have installed h5py package, you cannot save models.

Pre-built h5py wheels can be installed via pip from PyPI

```
$ pip install h5py
```